# How to make exeptions in .htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I am making a social networking site
and it currently looks like this

```
                              htdocs(xampp)
                                    |
 ___________________________________|___________________________________
 |                                                                      |
login(folder)                                                        index.html
```

if someone goes to http://localhost/index.html?u=Francis and the user Francis exists it will show them Francis profile, but if the user Francis does not exist it redirect them to login(folder)
then i used .htaccess to make it that instead of typing http://localhost/index.html?u=Francis you can type http://localhost/francis and it will show you Francis profile but i can't access http://localhost/login because there is no user like login so it keeps redirecting

how do I make it that all urls that look like `http://localhost/francis` **except** `http://localhost/login` it will show their profile,

my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.html?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.html?u=$1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide us code of your .htaccess?

Comment: @Vepthy my code is

Comment: @Vepthy                                                                                                                                                              RewriteEngine on                                                                                                                             RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.html?u=$1                                                                                   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.html?u=$1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write php code to check if user `Francis` exists,
you can't do that with htaccess,

you can also redirect to your login page or folder with php:

```
header('Location: ...');
```

[Documentation about header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

To show the users page I would suggest to make a new route for that, so something like `localhost/user/francis`:

```
RewriteRule user/(0-9a-zA-Z_-) index.php?u=$
```

Comment: @user13782016 You're very welcome, please accept my answer if you're happy with it :).